# select cartesian product from 2 tables with not equal (<>) where condition; postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, where-clause, cartesian-product

I need Cartesian product of the two tables MINUS combinations where two tables have same value in a field.

```
SELECT 
    table1.field1,
    table1.field2,
    table2.field3,
    table2.field4
FROM 
    table1, table2
WHERE 
    table1.field1 <> table2.field3;
```

Now, let's suppose that table1 and table2 have a million records each and that fields are indexed.
What is the most efficient way to retrieve the resultset in reasonable time?
Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Please note NOT EQUAL condition in where clause. I need cartesian product of the two tables MINUS combinations where two tables have same value in a field. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable way to generate a Cartesian product except where two fields are equal.

Comment: This is one Tera of results, 4 Tera of fields, the content of each field how many bytes? How many RAM do you have? Can you use the result, if it is split into multiple parts, maybe by "AND t1.f1 > 0 AND t1.f1 <= 100000" in ten steps. Is there a sequenced key involved in one of both queries? You could read the columns of both tables (2 Mega rows) and combine them with a programming language, but maybe postgresql is smart enough to solve the problem itself.

Comment: And you may restrict both tables to 1/10th and measure, how long it take, increase to 2/10th and so on, to estimate the time and find the threshold, from where the system gets unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach I can think of, other than the one already given in the question, is

```
SELECT 
  table1.field1,
  table1.field2,
  table2.field3,
  table2.field4
FROM 
  table1, table2
EXCEPT -- Postgresql, MINUS in Oracle
    SELECT 
  table1.field1,
  table1.field2,
  table2.field3,
  table2.field4
FROM 
  table1, table2
WHERE field1=field3;
```

Assuming `field1` and `field3` are indexed, and that the DB has some optimization for a full Cartesian join, this *might* be faster, it might be run the exact same way (use `EXPLAIN`), and it might be worse!